# Filter function using variable column reference

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, formula

I want to include a filtered list from a range on another sheet, where the column containing the filter criteria is identified based on whether the header value equals a key reference in my current sheet.

The range is Attendance!$A$2:$S$25, and I want it to be filtered on the condition Attendance![Column]$2:[Column]$25="In" where Attendance![Column]$1=$B$1, a key value in the current sheet.

I was able to produce what should be an appropriate string reference to the column to be searched in the filter function:

```
=left(address(1,match($B$1,Attendance!$A$1:$S$1,0),4,True,"Attendance"),12)&"2:"&left(address(1,match($B$1,Attendance!$A$1:$S$1,0),4,True),1)&"25"
```

Which produces `Attendance!G2:G25`, as an example, based on the current value of $B$1.

But when I add the filter function and requisite condition below, I recieve the common 'FILTER has mismatched range sizes.' error.

```
=filter(Attendance!$A$2:$S$25,(left(address(1,match($B$1,Attendance!$A$1:$S$1,0),4,True,"Attendance"),12)&"2:"&left(address(1,match($B$1,Attendance!$A$1:$S$1,0),4,True),1)&"25")="In")
```

How do I create this filtered list based on a variable filter criteria column?

Comment: I thought the functions in question operated the same way in both, hence the wider net, but apparently not. Edited.

Comment: Can you share (a) a sentence or two on the context & (b) an example table of what Attendance!A2:S25 looks like? Is this a table where the Headers are all dates and the values below are simply "IN" or "OUT"? Is the far left column something like student names? These details will likely help us find a better solution for you faster :)

Comment: Thanks for asking so kindly! Your assumption is more or less on the money, the first column on Attendance! has a header of "Name" and the subsequent values are all names of individuals. The headers for columns B:S are all dates, and the subsequent values are in a data validated option set of "In", "Maybe", "Out", and "Attended".

Comment: — awesome! In that case, I think the answer I've provided below will do exactly what you need without any edits (even though I have the names in col A instead of as the header :)

Comment: oh wow, just one function! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edit: I've updated the example spreadsheet linked below with new context and to include a selector to filter for "IN" or the other possible values.*

You are 99.999% of the way there!
**Just need to add an `INDIRECT()` function in the formula you already have**, like below:

```
=FILTER(Attendance!$A$2:$S$25,INDIRECT(IFNA(left(address(1,match($B$1,Attendance!$A$1:$S$1,0),4,True,"Attendance"),12)&"2:"&left(address(1,match($B$1,Attendance!$A$1:$S$1,0),4,True),1)&"25","no match found"))="IN")
```

Here's a link to an [example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z9WKuI9xGjbAQi27c8nk1mvQWZKJfAjLIjovuDE8dxs/edit?usp=sharing) implementing what I think you're describing.

Started by creating an "Attendance" tab:
[image: Started by creating an "Attendance" tab]

And here's the main sheet where the list filters by all those marked is `IN` for the column corresponding to what's in `B1`
Example 1: "Apple"
[image: filter for apple]

Example 2: "Maple"
[image]

IF you want to filter for more than just `IN`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generalized example scenario which you can try n' adapt...

```
=filter(Attendance!A2:S25,choosecols(Attendance!B2:S25,xmatch(B1,Attendance!B1:S1))="In")
```

[image]